# How would one read space separated input in Eiffel?

Tags: input, stream, eiffel

I can't really use `Io.read_integer` as that just ignores everything except
the first number.

I can use `Io.read_line` to get something like `15 14 59 86`.
How would I split these into integers now?

Javascript has `split()`, C++ has `stringstream`, something similar would be ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use only one space, there is a `split` method in the `{STRING}` class. The argument of the `split` method is a `{CHARACTER}` instead of a `{STRING}`. So, you have to use `' '` instead of `" "`. Here is a little function that do what I think you want.

```
split_to_integer_list(a_string:STRING):ARRAYED_LIST[INTEGER]
        -- Convert `a_string', a space separated list of integer
        -- into a {LIST} of {INTEGER}
    local
        l_split:LIST[STRING]
    do
        l_split := a_string.split (' ')
        create Result.make (a_string.count)
        across l_split as la_split loop
            if la_split.item.is_integer then
                Result.extend(la_split.item.to_integer)
            end
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to allow several spaces, tabs, etc. between the integers, you can use the class `{ST_SPLITTER}` from the Gobo library. Here is an example:

```
local
    l_line: STRING
    l_splitter: ST_SPLITTER
    l_list: DS_LINKED_LIST [INTEGER]
do
    io.read_line
    l_line := io.last_string
    create l_list.make
    create l_splitter.make_with_separators (" %T")
    across l_splitter.split (l_line) as l_split loop
        if l_split.item.is_integer then
            l_list.put_last (l_split.item.to_integer)
        end
    end
```